# Xcode Swift show data from CloudKit in tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, cloudkit

Hope someone can help me. Im trying to show data (privateData) from CloudKit in a UITableview with prototype cell, but my code do bot show my data stored in CloudKit. It's no problem to store the data.

My code are:

```
var arrayname = [CKRecord]()
var arraydate = [CKRecord]()

let privateDB = CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase
let cloudContainer = (CKContainer.defaultContainer().addOperation)

func loadData() {

    arrayname = [CKRecord]()

    let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Notes", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
    query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)]
    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results:[CKRecord]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if let arrayName = results {
            self.arrayname = arrayName
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }   
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayname.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainViewCell

    if arrayname.count == 0 {
        return cell
    }

    let name = arrayname[indexPath.row]

    if let nameContent = name["name"] as? String {
        cell.nameLabel?.text = nameContent
    }


    let date = arrayname[indexPath.row]

    if let dateContent = date["date_end"] as? String {
        cell.nameLabel?.text = dateContent
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: At what [step](http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/) are things going wrong?  Are you downloading the data successfully?  Is the downloaded data successfully being turned into usable Swift objects?  Is the table showing the expected number of rows and columns?  Is there a crash?

Comment: When i run the app in simulator there are no data showing in my tableview. I have no trouble saving data and i can see the data in my CloudKit Dashboard. (i am logged in via iCloud in the simulator setting). There are no crash

Comment: I have checked all my CloudKit setting, so the user have full access over the fields (read, write, query)

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work :-)  ...... First i had to make a Array for my objects with:

```
var arrayName: Array<CKRecord> = []
```

Then i query the data with:

```
 func loadData() {

    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let privateDatabase = container.privateCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Notes", predicate: predicate)

    privateDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }
        else {
            print(results)

            for result in results! {
                self.arrayName.append(result)
            }

            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.tableView.hidden = false
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Then i show the data in my tableview with :

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainViewCell

    let noteRecord: CKRecord = arrayName[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel?.text = noteRecord.valueForKey("name") as? String
    cell.dateLabel?.text = noteRecord.valueForKey("date_end") as? String

    return cell
}
```

Comment: i think it was that i did not put the cloud data in the array : var arrayName: Array<CKRecord> = []

Answer (score 0):

Flemming, the challenge with CloudKit sometimes is the timing. You see the completion clause almost certainly returns before the data is returned in some cases. Use this function [I found on SO, forgive me I don't recall the post] to delay the execution of the table fill [and ensure it happens on the main thread].

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
dispatch_after(
    dispatch_time(
        DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
        Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    ),
    dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

So you call with X the delay; don't know how much data we're talking or the speed of you link, so I cannot give you a value. But say, start with 20, if it works; par it down.

```
delay(X) {
  self.arrayname = arrayName     
  self.tableView.reloadData()        
}
```

Give me kudos if it works :)

Comment: Can't get it to work. The data i want to query are only text not images. I had i to work when i was using Parse to store the data.

Comment: If you go to the dashboard, you find data yes; what happened to the error here? You don't seem to be checking it? Put a else to give you something if there is no data in the table?